# Parse and ACL(check relation between an object ACL and user ACL

Tags: parse-platform

i am trying to build an android app with posts and comments 
the comments are shown in ListView using custom adapter
different user can comment on any post 
each time a comment is saved it is saved with public readaccess and private write access
there is also a delete and edit option for each comment in case user wanna delete or edit the comment
here i cannot understand how can i check if the current user has access control (ACL) over that data so that i may allow him to edit it
USING PARSE AS A BACKEND!
ANY HELP WOULD BE PRAISED